# Return cell value in Pandas multi-index dataframe as string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to return a single cell value from a dataframe of about 11.000 rows and 10 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : ('foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'),
                    'B' : ('horse', 'car', 'horse', 'car'),
                    'C' : ('red', 'green', 'blue', 'black')})
df
     A      B      C
 0  foo  horse    red
 1  foo    car  green
 2  bar  horse   blue
 3  bar    car  black
```

I've tried a few versions of loc, but always get an object returned, not the actual value ('green'). For instance:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'foo') & (df['B'] == 'car'), 'C']
```

returns:

```
1    green
Name: C, dtype: object
```

The result is correct, but it is returned as an object, not as a string. I also tried setting columns A and B as indices in a multi-index frame. The loc code is then easier, but same result.

So how can I get the value as a string, not as an object?

Comment: `df.loc[(df['A'] == 'foo') & (df['B'] == 'car'), 'C'].values[0]` would return `green`  as a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`item`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html#pandas-series-item):

> pandas.Series.item
>
> Series.item() return the first element of the underlying data
>   as a python scalar

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'foo') & (df['B'] == 'car'), 'C'].item()
```

Output:

```
'green'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a series out, and you want the first object.

You can think of what you are doing as getting the pd.Series equivalent of a list of length 1: `['green']`. If it was a list, you would do `list[0]`.

However, pandas series subset based on index, so you can't do this. To subset without knowledge of a series index, use `iloc[0]`:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'foo') & (df['B'] == 'car'), 'C'].iloc[0]

'green'
```